# Azure DevOps: Custom condition on task to be run if anything failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to send the notification if anything in the stage fails. How can I set the condition in the Release pipeline's task so the task is run when anything previously failed?

The marked option works only for the immediate predecessor.
[image]

But consider a situation there is a task which failed, then there is a task which will be run always and after that one is the task I want to run if anything fails.

Comment: The option "Only when a previous task has failed" is if any from task failed, not only the last one.

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread but in case someone is facing the same issue, I managed to achieve the condition "if anything fails" by using the predefined variable `[Agent.JobStatus]`. It has the following statuses :

1. Canceled
2. Failed
3. Succeeded
4. SucceededWithIssues (partially successful)

Having the values above I set the following custom condition:

```
eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues')
```

If you wish to have multiple custom conditions, you can use logical operators as follows :

```
or(eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Canceled'),eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'Failed'),eq(variables['Agent.JobStatus'], 'SucceededWithIssues'))
```

[image: Azure Devops custom condition]

**Result**:

[image]

*reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables*

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use custom condition and set it to `failed()`

quote:

> With no arguments, evaluates to True only if any previous job in the
>   dependency graph failed.

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-status-functions

Comment: `failed()` is an equivalent to option `Only when a previous task has failed`. This still doesn't help with my case mentioned in the original question.

Comment: If you check the yaml, you will see the `Only when a previous task has failed` is translated to condition `failed()`. Also when you set Custom codition to `failed()` it's automatically switched to `Only when a previous task has failed`. Anyway still it doesn't work for the scenario mentioned above.

Comment: this works for me in my pipeline xD does your failed task fail the build?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer, you need to use a custom condition and set it to `failed()`. But that alone won't do the trick. I believe you could achieve what you want by listing all the previous jobs being run before the `Notification` job in its `dependsOn` field. That way, if any of the listed jobs fails, your `Notification` job will be executed.

```
jobs:
- job: Build
  (...)
- job: CleanUp
  (...)
- job: Notification
      dependsOn: 
      - Build
      - Cleanup
      condition: failed()
      steps:
        - task: (...)
```